# How to write a main url rewrite in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to change the url: `www.example.com/index.html?id=roy` to:
`www.example.com/roy`

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx), but it is for the url: `www.example.com/users/roy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem:
 try_files $uri/ $uri /index.html?$query_string

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try. This rewrites `/(.+)` to `/index.html?id=$1`.

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.html?id=$1 last;
```

Comment: i get 500 Internal Server Error,also when i type www.somedomain.com, why ?

Comment: Please post your configuration

Answer (score 0):

try this, (use of infinite names)

```
location / {
  rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/users/$arg_id permanent;
}
```