# nginx rewrite directory to file

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, ubuntu-14.04

I've got a quick situation that I need help with.
I'm using nginx and I'm really new to the system, and need a rewrite rule that would rewrite the following:
http://website.com/folderName/somePage.php to http://website.com/somePage
Please note that somePage will change depending on the file. 
How can I make it globally recognizable instead of having to make a separate rewrite rule for each page? Can you please fix this code?

I've used the following:

```
rewrite ^/$ /FolderName/$.php last;
```

The above line doesnt work and nginx fails to restart

Any help would be great!

Thanks so much in advance. :)

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguous question - I need rewrite code! thanks!

Comment: You know that SO do not provide code? We are here to help if you have an issue...anyway... have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z]+)$ /folderName/$1.php last;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding it to `try_files`, of course you can reorder this according to your priorities.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /index.php;
```