# how to handle URLs in PHP

Tags: php, url

I am creating job portal website. In that, for displaying job I use `job.php?id='ID'` i.e http://localhost/job.php?id=1 in URL. 
I want  to display it by using job title and location not id.
 For example:

Job Title is : "PHP developer" and the Location is: "London"
 So I want to display URL like 
 http://localhost/PHP-developer-jobs-in-London/ 
 How to display this in PHP?

Comment: Try this article.
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/seo-friendly-urls-with-php.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use your HTTP server to rewrite the URL to a PHP-script. Useful answers here on Stack Owerflow:

If you are on Apache server: [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

If you are on nginx: [How to write a url rewrite in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

try .htaccess url rewrite method

sample .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^jobs/([^/]*)$ job.php?job_title=$1 [L]
```

Refer this link:
https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: yep. its different between different web servers though. your example is for Apache.