# Nginx rewrite URL, change parts of URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Is it possible in Nginx to rewrite URL like this?

```
http://www.example.com/city/person/contact.php?id=name
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/city/person/name/contact
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a url rewrite in nginx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
location ~ /city/person/(.*)/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/city/person/$2.php?id=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: No :-( I get this error message: [emerg] 1084#0: invalid number of arguments in "rewrite" directive in

Comment: Sorry, it should be: `rewrite /city/person/(.*)/(.*) ^/city/person/$2.php?id=$1 last;` Probably don't need the location {}