# How to make simple Nginx rewrite rule

Tags: php, url, nginx, url-rewriting

i am new to Nginx and i want to do simple URL rewrite but i don't know how to do it. I want to my link look like this: `**localhost/some/path/to/file** and real link is: **localhost/index.php?url=/some/path/to/file**`. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a url rewrite in nginx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx)

Comment: Do you have a working PHP configuration? Edit you question and add more details, such as the nginx `server` configuration block.