# rewrite nginx dynamic link

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i have this problem with my link:
incomming:

```
https://example.org/api/v1/1122/do_some_php_stuff.php?search=13
```

My Problem with this link: 1122 is always an other objectnumber

So, I want to rewrite it to:

```
https://expample.org/1122
```

https:example.org/api/v1 is always the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a url rewrite in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx)