# nginx redirect based on specific query string

Tags: regex, wordpress, nginx, redirect

I am trying to redirect based on a specific query string:

https://foo.com/wp-login.php?action=register
to
https://foo.com/account/

```
location ~* /(wp-login\.php) {
        if ($query_string = "action=register") {
                rewrite ^ https://foo.com/account/ permanent;
        }

    limit_req zone=xwplogin burst=1 nodelay;
    #limit_conn xwpconlimit 30;
    auth_basic "Private";
    #auth_basic_user_file /home/nginx/domains/foo.com/htpasswd_wplogin;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php-wpsc.conf;
    # https://community.centminmod.com/posts/18828/
    #include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php-rediscache.conf;
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue? What do you get?

Comment: Nothing happens, no redirect happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
  # ...
  rewrite ^/wp-login\.php\?action=register$ https://foo.com/account/ permanent;
  # ...
}
```

Comment: @JCats I cant believe it's not working! would you please add server block?

Comment: Yes I had added it to the location / block

Comment: @JCats maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx) help you