# How to get REQUEST_URI like "domen/folder" in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

Please, help me with one question!
I'he got project with structure like:

[image]

And index.php like

[image]

When i type in browser mysite/blablabla i got

[image]

but when I type "mysite/folder1" - browser just open this folder.

How can I get REUEST_URI like "mysite/folder1" or "mysite/folder2"

I use OpenServer (nginx). Sorry if I explain poorly, bad English.

This file: nginx.conf from C:/nginx

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        off;
keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  onix-academy-php-framework;
    root   d:/dropbox/onix-academy-php-framework;
    index  index.php;
    #autoindex  on;
    
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include       fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

This file: nginx.conf from OpenServer

```
server {
listen                    %ip%:%httpport%;
listen                    %ip%:%httpsport% ssl;
server_name               %host% %aliases%;
root                      '%hostdir%';
#autoindex                 on;
index                     index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate           '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.crt';
ssl_certificate_key       '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.key';
#ssl_trusted_certificate  '';

# Disable MIME sniffing
add_header X-Content-Type-Options 'nosniff' always;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        include        '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt';
    }
    
    #location ^~ /Classes/ {
    #   return 302 /;
    #}
}
```

When I use "autoindex on" folders just open:
[image]

And when I commented "#autoindex on" I get 403 forbidden:
[image]

Comment: When you say the browser "opens the folder", what do you see? A listing of files? Or the result of a different PHP script?

Comment: just listing of files

Comment: and if you add index.php to your folder?

Comment: u mean that i need to add index.php to every folder in project to get request_uri with folder names ?

Comment: If you want echoing anything from a php file in a folder the most common way is to add an index.php in the folder and then call its through mysite/myfolder/

Comment: i just want to echo request_uri like "mysite/folder" and dont open this folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a url rewrite in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329316/how-to-write-a-url-rewrite-in-nginx)

Comment: no, its just a redirection, and request_uri will be == "/new_place_where_we_redirect_request", but not a "/folder1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your nginx to send all incoming requests with a handoff to PHP.

[Symfony has a simple setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) documented. Although it is tailored to symfony, it can be used for standard PHP as well.

Try replacing the `server` part of your first config with this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  onix-academy-php-framework;
    root   d:/dropbox/onix-academy-php-framework;
    index  index.php;
    #autoindex  on;

    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;

       # not sure if this one is needed, try it with or without:
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
       include       fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

Comment: I added nginx conf to my post

Comment: "You need to setup your nginx to send all incoming requests with a handoff to PHP"
dont know how to do it (

Comment: I've added a config you can try. If it doesn't work, please note any error messages that might be thrown in the nginx logs

Comment: I just tried your confin and its work great!!!! Thank you!!! )))

You are the best!